# how to change an error message to a custom one in php

Tags: php

I'm getting a date from a sql query and passing it to php sometimes I get this error message

> Warning: date_format () expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given in

this is because some fields are null as I do to change that message when the fields are null for something that says 'No date record'

```
<td><?=$fhi=date_format($key[9], 'Y/m/d');?></td>
```

Comment: You validate the data before trying to use it. If the validation fails, you show an error message. _Never_ assume that data that doesn't come from you directly are valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can (should ?) check if the value is `null` **before** trying to use it.

```
<?= $fhi = isset($key[9]) ? date_format($key[9], 'Y/m/d') : ("No date record"); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary operator to see if the value is null or not. If `$key[9]` is null, then display some other message - else use `date_format()`.

```
<?= $fhi = $key[9] === null ? 'No date record' : date_format($key[9], 'Y/m/d'); ?>
```